# Invoking Scala class' primary constructor with an implicit parameter inside an auxiliary constructor

Tags: scala

The class definition with compiling error:

```
class Foo(implicit x : Int) {
  def this(s : String) = this(s.length)
}
```

and the class definition can pass compiling

```
class Foo(implicit x : Int) {
  def this(s : String) = this()(s.length)
}
```

from my point view, the first definition is just correct. 
Since the auxiliary constructor explicitly called the primary constructor which expected a Integer as parameter, seems nothing wrong. 
And for the second class definition which pass compiling, actually I don't quite understand why it works.

Comment: seems like compiler hadn't generated primary constructor in your first example and can't resolve call to `Foo(Int)`

Answer (score 1):

In Scala every auxiliary constructor must invoke another constructor of the same class as its first action.

Also, you **do not have** a constructor with an `Int` parameter.
You have constructor with an `implicit` (Int) parameter.
You can either provide the implicit parameter in the scope or pass it explicitly writing something like `this()(9)`

Comment: thanks, but what does this()(9) comes from? or I need to just take it as a fact. actually I searched the scala documentation and Nothing related to this strange syntax.